# Creating a Live USB with minimal files at root?

Tags: live-usb

I want to have an EDC flash drive with the option to boot Ubuntu from it, but the default set up makes for a really messy root directory with all of the important files. Any possible way I can reduce it to one or two folders and still boot easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, no. That is Ubuntu disc structure and it cannot be modified.

The main image with all the contents resides in `casper/filesystem.squashfs`.

The `boot` folder contains `grub` bootloader so can't be removed.

The `dists` and `pool` folders contains some packages that ubuntu installs.

`EFI` is also important for newer computers.

Comment: I guess I can put them in a folder then move them to root with my phone or similar before plugging it in. Thanks for the little lesson too!